# Transform JSON form front end so it fits what API expects

Tags: javascript, json, api

I have the following data structure held in state by my React application.

```
{"assetNum": "SP234",
 "eventDate": "2021-08-15 08:30:00Z",
 "manufacturers": {
          "part1":"mfg1",
          "part2":"mfg2",
          "part3":"mfg3"},
 "part1":{
          "inlet":[true, true, true, true, true],
          "outlet":[false, false, false, false, false]}
 "part2":{
          "inlet":[false, false true, true, true],
          "outlet":[false, false, false, false, false]}
 "part3":{
          "suction":[true, true, true, true, true],
          "discharge":[false, false, false, false, false]}
  }
```

On the other end I have a .NET API expecting the following data structure:

```
{"assetNum": "SP234",
 "eventDate": "2021-08-15 08:30:00Z",
 "details":[
        {"part":"part1",
         "label":"inlet",
         "manufacturer":"mfg1",
         "locations":[true, true, true, true, true]},
        {"part":"part1",
         "label":"outlet",
         "manufacturer":"mfg1",
         "locations":[false, false, false, false, false]},
        {"part":"part2",
         "label":"inlet",
         "manufacturer":"mfg2",
         "locations":[false, false, true, true, true]},
        {"part":"part2",
         "label":"outlet",
         "manufacturer":"mfg2",
         "locations":[false, false, false, false, false]},
        {"part":"part3",
         "label":"suction",
         "manufacturer":"mfg3",
         "locations":[true, true, true, true, true},
        {"part":"part3",
         "label":"fischarge",
         "manufacturer":"mfg3",
         "locations":[false, false, false, false, false]},
      ]
    }
```

I'm trying to avoid changing the state on the front-end since a lot of other things already depend on it. I'm also trying to avoid changing the API.

How can I go about transforming one object into the other structure anytime the user clicks "SUBMIT"? I was thinking of creating a class with a constructor and a method to generate the other JSON but that might be an overkill? I'm hoping there's a straightforward way to do this in Javascript that I haven't learned yet.

Thanks to all in advance,

Comment: what does your code currently do `anytime the user clicks "SUBMIT"` - without that the whole of the question can't be answered - though, I've given you a very simple way to transform the data

Comment: Probably most clean to store it in the right format in the the first place. Meaning reworking how your react state works.

Comment: Thanks for your answers. To clarify when the users click "SUBMIT" the website will send a POST request to the C# endpoint. One more thing is that the boolean lists can be of different lengths, using the object approach will still work right? Since the "Value" part can be a list of variable length "N"

Comment: the length of the boolean arrays is irrelevant - whatever is there will be used in the output (at least, in my answer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easily achieved using ...
2 x [Object.entries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries)
[Array#map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)
and
[Array#flatMap](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap)

```js
const input = {
    "assetNum": "SP234",
    "eventDate": "2021-08-15 08:30:00Z",
    "manufacturers": {
        "part1": "mfg1",
        "part2": "mfg2",
        "part3": "mfg3"
    },
    "part1": {
        "inlet": [true, true, true, true, true],
        "outlet": [false, false, false, false, false]
    },
    "part2": {
        "inlet": [false, false, true, true, true],
        "outlet": [false, false, false, false, false]
    },
    "part3": {
        "suction": [true, true, true, true, true],
        "discharge": [false, false, false, false, false]
    }
};
const output = {
    assetNum: input.assetNum,
    eventDate: input.eventDate,
    details: Object.entries(input.manufacturers).flatMap(([part, manufacturer]) => Object.entries(input[part]).map(([label, locations]) => ({ part, label, manufacturer, locations})))
};
console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Object.keys` and map your objects

code:

```
const data = {
    "assetNum": "SP234",
    "eventDate": "2021-08-15 08:30:00Z",
    "manufacturers": {
        "part1": "mfg1",
        "part2": "mfg2",
        "part3": "mfg3"
    },
    "part1": {
        "inlet": [true, true, true, true, true],
        "outlet": [false, false, false, false, false]
    },
    "part2": {
        "inlet": [false, false, true, true, true],
        "outlet": [false, false, false, false, false]
    },
    "part3": {
        "suction": [true, true, true, true, true],
        "discharge": [false, false, false, false, false]
    }
};


let model = {
    "assetNum": data.assetNum,
    "eventDate": data.eventDate,
    "details": []
}

Object.keys(data.manufacturers).forEach(key=>{
    const row = data[key]

    Object.keys(row).forEach(innerKey=>{
        let item = {
            "manufacturer":data.manufacturers[key],
            "part": key,
            "label": innerKey,
            "locations": row[innerKey]
        }
    
        model.details.push(item)
    })   
})

console.log(model)
```

Comment: Have you tested your result and compared it to the requirement?